# What is the minimum strength of a magnetosphere needed to sustain life?

Tags: planet, magnetic-field

On Earth, the magnetic field intensity is roughly between 25,000 - 65,000 nT. Assume for a second that we have a planet with double the atmospheric thickness of Earth but with a similar composition. How weak can such a planet's magnetic field be, yet still be capable of protecting the planet's atmosphere and the life that lives on it?

Comment: Venus has virtually no magnetic field and yet 100x the atmospheric surface pressure than Earth... so works without?

Comment: @planetmaker: Not only that, but Venus is nearer to the Sun than Earth & experiences are higher "erosive" flux of solar particles.  Additionally, being closer to the Sun, solar induced temperatures of the atmosphere would be higher than for planets beyond Venus.

Comment: Basically your question is based on a false premise, or at a minimum incomplete reasoning. I don't think it's a good fit for Astronomy SE in its current form.